# Array includes reurning false, even with the presence of value in data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to check, either if the id is present or not in the array of ids.

On console.log I could see as follows:

```
3  //console.log(r_id)

(2) [1, 3] //console.log(ids)

false //console.log(ids.includes(r_id));
```

I could not find why it is showing `false` even when there is `3` in the array.

### Update:

Full code:

```
var ids = [];
resp.data.map(function(e) {
    ids.push(e.id);
});
console.log(r_id);
console.log(ids);

console.log(ids.includes(r_id));


if(ids.includes(r_id) === false ){
    r_id = resp.data[0].id;
}
```

Actually, I am trying to check if r_id is not in array then set new `r_id` as the first element of array else keep the old r_id as new r_id

**On server side:**

print_r($data)

```
<pre>Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => Data One
                    [distance] => 0
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [name] => Data Three
                    [distance] => 4.02
                )

        )

)
</pre>
```

This data was sent as a json response as follows:

```
return response()->json([
           'status' => '200',
           'data' => $data
        ]);
```

Comment: Are you sure id is a number? Try using ids.includes(+id);

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Please include the real case instead of the console game.

Comment: Includes method is strict matching, Although, make sure id value is set

Comment: Are you sure the ids in the array and the id you are search are of the same type. Probably the ids in the array are stored as strings and the id you search is a number (or the other way round).

Comment: @Sreeram thank you it seems working with your suggestion.

Comment: Why are you allocating an array and then filling that by treating `map` as a `forEach`? Just _use map, that's literally what it's for_: `let ids = resp.data.map(e => e.id);` done, `ids` is now an array of id values. However, remember to make sure that if you need them to be numbers, that you convert them to numbers, and if you need them to be strings, that you convert them to strings. Even if "they might already be". Make sure, by writing code that makes sure.

Comment: I guess we will have a clear picture if you post the data that you receive in resp.data!

Answer (score 2):

I am just posting this answer to make it clear that this issue is solved.

I followed `Sreeram` comments and make it work.

I realized it was the issue due to string and number comparision. That means I could get it true either doing one of following:

```
console.log(ids.includes(+r_id));
```

OR

```
console.log(ids.includes(Number(r_id)));
```